# Update attributes using UpdateItemEnhancedRequest - DynamoDbEnhancedClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

As per DynamoDb Java Sdk2, the Update operation can be performed as

```
DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
Key key = Key.builder()
          .partitionValue(keyVal)
          .build();
Customer customerRec = mappedTable.getItem(r->r.key(key));
customerRec.setEmail(email);
mappedTable.updateItem(customerRec);
```

1. Shouldn't this will cause two calls to dynamoDB
2. What if after fetching the record and before updateItem call, another thread updated the record, so we have to put it into a transaction as well

Although there is another way by using UpdateItemEnhancedRequest

```
final var request = UpdateItemEnhancedRequest.builder(Customer.class)
        .item(updatedCustomerObj)
        .ignoreNulls(Boolean.TRUE)
        .build();
    mappedTable.updateItem(request);
```

but this would require using ignoreNulls(TRUE) and will not handle updates in case null value is to be set.

What should be the optimized way for update operation using enhanced client

Comment: Depends on your needs. What exactly do you want to do? In case #1 you seem to care about the values that on the table as you read the item first. In case #2 you do not care, as you just blindly update the item. What functionality do you need?

Comment: @smac2020 DB call would also occur here right?

Customer customerRec = mappedTable.getItem(r->r.key(key));

Comment: correct - that is another call

Answer (score 2):

***For 1:***

I don't like this part of the SDK but the "non-enhanced" client can update without first querying for the entity.

```
    UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = UpdateItemRequest
            .builder()
            .tableName("Customer")
            .key(
                    Map.of(
                            "PK", AttributeValue.builder().s("pk").build(),
                            "SK", AttributeValue.builder().s("sk").build()
                    ))
            .attributeUpdates(
                    Map.of(
                            "email", AttributeValueUpdate.builder()
                                            .action(AttributeAction.PUT)
                                            .value(AttributeValue.builder().s("new-email@gmail.com").build())
                                    .build()
                    ))
            .build();
    client.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

***For 2:***

Yes, you are absolutely right that can happen and will lead to data inconsistency. To avoid this you should use conditional write/update with a version. Luckily we have a Java annotation for this

```
@DynamoDBVersionAttribute
public Long getVersion() { return version; }
public void setVersion(Long version) { this.version = version;}
```

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html)